# Curley braces are not working in regular expression in C language

Tags: c, regex

The Curly braces{} are not working in C language Regular expressions, it is always giving output as NO match , if i give correct input as "ab" or "ac". I would request to help in this case.

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <regex.h>
  #include <stdio.h>


   int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ regex_t regex;
        int reti;
        char msgbuf[100];

        /* Compile regular expression */
        reti = regcomp(&regex, "[a-c]{2}", 0);
        if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); return(1); }

        /* Execute regular expression */
        reti = regexec(&regex, "ab", 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }
        else{
                regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
                return 1;
        }

       /* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
        regfree(&regex);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the Basic Regular Expressions dialect that has no knowledge of the quantifier `{n}` in the regex.

One solution would be to supply the option `REG_EXTENDED` as the last argument instead of 0 when creating your `regex_t` object.

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[a-c]{2}", REG_EXTENDED);
```

See http://ideone.com/oIBXxu for a Demo of your code with my modification.

---

As Casimir et Hippolyte notes in the comments Basic Regular Expressions support the `{}` quantifier as well but the curly braces must be escaped with a `\` in the regex which again has to be escaped in the C string as `\\`. So you can use the line

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[a-c]\\{2\\}", 0);
```

as well as an alternative to the solution above(running Demo with this line modified under http://ideone.com/x7vlIO).

You can check http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html for more information about the difference between Basic and Extended Regular Expressions.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you can always use the BRE syntax: `reti = regcomp(&regex, "[a-c]\\{2\\}", 0);`

Comment: Thanks a Lot for your answer. The problem got fixed.

Comment: The output is showing as always match if i give wrong input .               reti = regcomp(&regex, "[a-c]{4}", REG_EXTENDED);
        if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); return(1); }

/* Execute regular expression */
        reti = regexec(&regex, "abcbddddddd", 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }

Comment: BRE in c has the `{n}` quantifier, you only need to escape curly brackets. http://ideone.com/x7vlIO

Comment: @user1720713 This problem occurs because you use the wrong regex. Your version of `regexec` matches if your regex is found anywhere in your string. If you only want to match whole lines that suffice your regex add the regex special characters`^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, so change your regex to `^[a-c]{2}$`

Comment: Even i changed as per suggestion, the output is showing always as "Match" if i give wrong input.                                                                    reti = regcomp(&regex, "[a-c]\\{2\\}", 0);
        if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); return(1); }

/* Execute regular expression */
        reti = regexec(&regex, "acdbdffdgdh", 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }

Comment: @user1720713 Again you forgot `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of your regex to match the whole line

Comment: But Actual;y i need to implement for this regular expression is :                  "[0-9a-f]{4}\\.[0-9a-f]{4}\\.[0-9a-f]{4}";  In this case how do i use ^ and $

Comment: @user1720713 `"^[0-9a-f]{4}\\.[0-9a-f]{4}\\.[0-9a-f]{4}$"` The symbol `^` at the beginning means *match beginning of line* and the `$` at the end means *match end of a line*

Comment: @user1720713 The best way to say thank you is accepting the answer that helped http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer :)

Comment: Can You provide the correct pattern for this string                                 [0-9a-fA-F]{4}(.[0-9a-fA-F]{4}){2}